# Preview an many image before it is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, preview

For the first input it works well, but not for the second. Instead of updating the second one it updates the first. How do I separate this two input previews with the same function?

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" required>
<img id="load" src="../img/preview.png" alt="loading" width=50 height=50>

<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" required>
<img id="load" src="../img/preview.png" alt="loading" width=50 height=50>
```

Comment: What input, what function? Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the IDs should be unieque, so set "load" to "load1" and "load2" for the img element.
And you should distinguish the output target by the input.
`$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);` always updates the element '#blah'.
Therefore, add an argument to the readURL() that specifies the output destination, and modify it to update there.

```
    function readURL(input, target) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
    
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          $(target).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
    
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
      }
    }
```

```
    <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this, '#load1');" required>
    <img id="load1" src="../img/preview.png" alt="loading" width=50 height=50>
    
    <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this, '#load2');" required>
    <img id="load2" src="../img/preview.png" alt="loading" width=50 height=50>
```